# looping through JSON array in shell script using for loop

Tags: shell, scripting, json, jq

Below is the curl command output, need script or command to print "doc_count" less than 10 and save the "key" in output.txt file.

```
{
  "took": 117,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1005,
    "successful": 1005,
    "skipped": 979,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 205,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "2": {
      "doc_count": 205,
      "bg_count": 5778,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "51.79.100.225",
          "doc_count": 24,
          "score": 3.1826769779892925,
          "bg_count": 24
        },
        {
          "key": "169.45.76.172",
          "doc_count": 13,
          "score": 1.7239500297442,
          "bg_count": 13
        },
        {
          "key": "198.147.22.235",
          "doc_count": 10,
          "score": 1.3261154074955384,
          "bg_count": 10
        },
        {
          "key": "5.178.86.74",
          "doc_count": 8,
          "score": 0.9386793575252826,
          "bg_count": 9
        },
        {
          "key": "35.193.189.85",
          "doc_count": 7,
          "score": 0.928280785246877,
          "bg_count": 7
        },
        {
          "key": "5.101.0.209",
          "doc_count": 6,
          "score": 0.7956692444973231,
          "bg_count": 6
        },
        {
          "key": "103.102.138.250",
          "doc_count": 4,
          "score": 0.5304461629982153,
          "bg_count": 4
        },
        {
          "key": "194.60.254.128",
          "doc_count": 4,
          "score": 0.5304461629982153,
          "bg_count": 4
        },
        {
          "key": "222.186.19.221",
          "doc_count": 4,
          "score": 0.5304461629982153,
          "bg_count": 4
        },
        {
          "key": "109.234.153.132",
          "doc_count": 4,
          "score": 0.5304461629982153,
          "bg_count": 4
        },
        {
          "key": "110.173.179.66",
          "doc_count": 4,
          "score": 0.5304461629982153,
          "bg_count": 4
        },
        {
          "key": "81.92.200.229",
          "doc_count": 4,
          "score": 0.5304461629982153,
          "bg_count": 4
        },
        {
          "key": "109.234.153.131",
          "doc_count": 4,
          "score": 0.5304461629982153,
          "bg_count": 4
        },
        {
          "key": "109.234.153.133",
          "doc_count": 3,
          "score": 0.39783462224866156,
          "bg_count": 3
        },
        {
          "key": "182.59.108.9",
          "doc_count": 3,
          "score": 0.39783462224866156,
          "bg_count": 3
        },
        {
          "key": "178.137.19.29",
          "doc_count": 6,
          "score": 0.3514721090925732,
          "bg_count": 13
        },
        {
          "key": "178.137.17.210",
          "doc_count": 3,
          "score": 0.23284711481261156,
          "bg_count": 5
        },
        {
          "key": "5.178.86.78",
          "doc_count": 3,
          "score": 0.19160023795359907,
          "bg_count": 6
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "status": 200
}
```

Comment: They appear to _all_ be less than 100, at least the ones in the `.buckets[]` array. What do you mean "in 24 hours"? There doesn't seem to be any timestamp information in the data. Is the `"2"` substructure of the document always called `"2"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jq -r '.aggregations."2".buckets[] | select(.doc_count < 100).key' file.json
```

This would select the elements in the `.aggregations."2".buckets[]` array that have a `.doc_count` of less than 100, and then get the `.key` value for each of those.

Redirect the result of this to a file to save it.

Comment: actually i want the shell script using for loop to display above output that u mention above. @Kusalananda

Comment: @shaileshsalunkhe The command that I have given you will display the `.key` values. There is no need for a loop in a shell script.

Comment: @shaileshsalunkhe Sorry, that makes no sense. You have the output, then you can use that to do whatever you want with it (for example, loop over it like you would loop over the lines of any text, if you wish).  The `jq` command will produce the `.key` values. This is what your question asked for.